# Redirect HTML to PHP with Parameters

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I am no web developer and this may be a simple(yet unusual) task, but I have found no solution so far.

On my Webserver (*Apache2*), I have two files:

**index.html**

**test.php**

The test.php needs some parameters to function properly, so I have to call the file this way for example:

*www.mydomain.com/test.php?parameter=true*

My goal is that I can call the test.php file, when I open the index.html file. 
For example:

*www.mydomain.com/index.html?parameter=true*

This should redirect to/execute test.php AND pass the parameter. Is there any solution for this?

Please note:
**The index.html file is a must**, I may not replace it with index.php or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to use JavaScript for this, but it is doable. On the page load, call something like this:

```
location = "test.php?" + location.search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will be a good practice or no but here I have found something which you may try.

Since your execution will start from the html file, you can include a JavaScript code in it and write a code to redirect to necessary URL

e.g.
In your html, you can include a script as follows -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/test.php/?parameter=true";
</script>
```

You may also add script to replace
the 'index.html' with 'test.php'
 in your current URL via JavaScript which will redirect you to desired place.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the '<head></head>' tags of the index.html page, place the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.yourdomain.com/test.php"  + window.location.search;
</script>
```

The 'window.location.search' part gets the query string from the URL. The query string is the part of the URL that follows and includes the question mark (?).

- http://www.yourdomain.com/test.php***?hello=world&eddard=stark***

Now, everytime someone comes to your page they will immediately be redirected to test.php with the all the accompanying parameters.